# gcc error trying to install PIL in a Python2.6 virtualenv

Tags: python, gcc, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv with the --no-site-packages option. I get an error trying to install PIL:

http://pastebin.com/SVqxs1sC

```
...
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/build/pil/setup.py'; execfile('/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/build/pil/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-t_oikl-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 120, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 165, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options)
  File "/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1243, in install
    requirement.install(install_options)
  File "/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 540, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 226, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command /home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/build/pil/setup.py'; execfile('/home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/build/pil/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-t_oikl-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/dustin/.virtualenvs/django1.2/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
```

Can someone help me with this?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to install python-dev package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: I'm on a windows 7 environment. How do I go about installing python-dev?

Comment: I had to install `python2.6-dev` in my situation since virtualenv is using 2.6.  Just a heads up for anyone else

Comment: `yum install python-devel` if you're on CentOS/RHEL.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the full listing on your pastebin link the line

```
_imaging.c:75:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

is the problem.

The gcc command line has

```
-I/usr/include/python2.6
```

there so that would be where it would expect to find it and that's where it is on my Mandriva system.

Perhaps you have python installed but not the development libraries which would be in the corresponding "-devel" version of the package?

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install python-dev - is very good, but
if you use few pythons on your host system, and python2.6 is default.

If you try to:

```
 virtualenv -p python2.7
```

, go to the  bin directory, say source activate,
than:

```
pip install PIL
```

You get error like this: _imaging.c:75:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory

You should say!:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```