# flask says No module named PIL

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I am a flask newbie. I want to use PIL module in flask. However after writing my code, when I try to start my server, I get an error that `ImportError: No module named PIL`. What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have PIL or Pillow installed? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579995/django-no-module-named-pil

Comment: Yup I have it installed on my machine and importable via python interpreter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the module using pip or easy_install:

```
pip install Pillow
```

[Pillow 2.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1)

Comment: I already have it installed in my machine. Accessible using python interpreter. Or am I missing something here

Comment: Do you use virtual environment? How do you use PIL in your project? Note: Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports “import _imaging”. Please use “from PIL.Image import core as _imaging” instead.

Comment: yes i use virtual environment. But wait, do I need to install PIL inside flask also?

Comment: I do have PIL installed in python directory

Comment: Go to your virtualenv, then type `pip freeze` to see whether PIL or PILLow exist. If not, install it.

Comment: installing PIL in flask now, Thanks :)