# Cannot install psycopg2 on virtualenv

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2

Hi I use manjaro Linux and I tryed to install psycopg2 packge inside virtualenv but it gave errror `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. Then in the console I tryed `gcc --version` it  said`bash: gcc not found`. Am I supposed to install first gcc in order to install psycopg2. Or are there any solution? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967224/gcc-error-trying-to-install-pil-in-a-python2-6-virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

If You use Linux, to install gcc execute in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

or

`sudo yum install gcc`

depending on your OS

Comment: I solved problem. It is because of gcc. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install gcc. You might also need to install the python-dev package for your distribution. This is needed in cases where the module you are installing uses code written in C/C++.

Comment: When I tryied to install gcc through base-devel it gives this message `glibc=2.19 required`. But when I checked glibc=2.19 is installed in my system